# Differential signals in micro-coax

Tags: differential, coax

I have seen many applications where micro-coax is used for differential signals. For example display panels with LVDS or eDP, and a [I-PEX VS](https://www.i-pex.com/product/cabline-vs) type connector.
The I-PEX connector even names USB4, HDMI etc. in its applications.

But how do you get the right differential impedance, if you run each of the signals in a separate coaxial cable?

While doing some research I came across the term *twinax*, which is coax with dual inner conductors. Is that what is usually used, or can you run a differential signal in two coaxial cables?

I found this ["Micro coaxial Connectors Handbook"](https://www.bce.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/KEL-Micro-Coaxial-Connectors-BCE.pdf) stating for example LVDS as typical use case for micro-coaxial cable.
[image]

Comment: Please add a schematic of an example you have seen.

Comment: @Andyaka I have no examples with full schematics, but I added one more place I have found that mentions LVDS to be used with micro-coax. I have some display datasheets using this type of connector, but they are under NDA. But it seems to be pretty much standard when looking at cable manufacturers for I-PEX VS and similar connectors, that they advertise micro-coax for all types of applications with high-speed differential signals.

Comment: You can use two 50 ohm single ended coaxial cables for single 100 ohm differential signal, unless there is something special that prevents it. Can you be more specific if this answers your question already or is there something that needs clarification?

Comment: @Klas-Kenny `But how do you get the right differential impedance, if you run each of the signals in a separate coaxial cable?` - how could it not be the right impedance? Where are you having difficulties with this concept? In the absence of a tangible example, this comment returns to you to justify your problem.

Comment: @Andyaka Well, afaik the impedance is depending on the ratio of capacitance and inductance between the two conductors. So if these two conductors are completely shielded from each other, I don't know what happens to the impedance. I could guess that the two 50 Ω to ground in "series" will result in 100 Ω differential impedance ("throug" the ground?), but I want to know, not guess. Preferably citing some trustworthy source or at least a good explanation.

Comment: Are you aware that for a length of coax at low to moderate frequencies, the shield can be regarded as having zero inductance and hence it projects itself as a faraday cage along the extending length. It gets more complex as frequency rises (the coax behaves like a transmission line) but, impedance is maintained. Is it this that is what you might be missing @Klas-Kenny